# 'include' of functions in groovy scripts

Tags: groovy

I'm writing a number of scripts in groovy. And I need some kind of code reuse in my scripts.
How can I do it?

1. I can put this code in a class. But it is hardly to support solution - part of code is in the interpreted script and the other is in compiled class
2. I can use 'evaluate', but I need reuse of a function, which has return value. I tried "evaluate" of functions definitions and it seems to be not working.

Can you recommend some approach of "include" of functions definitions in a script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to compile the groovy script, you can include a script defined as a class just fine.

Take a file SomeClass.groovy

```
class SomeClass {
    def add(a,b){
        return a+b
    }
}
```

and a script SomeScript.groovy

```
println(new SomeClass().add(1,1))
```

This will work as long as SomeClass.groovy is on the CLASSPATH.

**EDITS**

```
class SomeClass {
    def static add(a,b){
        return a+b
    }
}
```

Call as:

```
println(SomeClass.add(1,1))
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!
Can I in such way also call functions outside of a class?

Comment: @Pavel, if you declare the add method as static, you can call it without the new.  This is probably as close as you can get. See edits.

Comment: Sure, you could use the class as a Mixin.  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Runtime+mixins